# La consulta no me trae resultados, alguna sugerencia?

Tags: laravel, carbon

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
$rate = Rate::where('created_at', Carbon\Carbon::now()); 
// También la hago asi: $rate = Rate::where('created_at', Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))->first();
```

De otra manera:

```
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
$date = new DateTime($now);

$rate = Rate::where('created_at', $date->format('Y-m-d')); // También la hago así: $rate = Rate::where('created_at', $date->format('Y-m-d'))->first();
```

Y siempre me responde con un NULL habiendo un registro con la fecha de hoy en la base de datos.

Comment: De todos modos, `H:m:s` es incorrecto, lo correcto es `H:i:s` dado que `m` es para meses con doble digito e `i` para minutos con doble digito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comentarios:

- Pasar a `$now` como argumento de la clase `DateTime` es algo redundante pues Carbon se construye y extiende sobre la clase de PHP llamada: [**`DateTime`**](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)
- No necesitas incluso tampoco el namespace `Carbon\Carbon` pues Laravel te ofrece un *helper* para acceder a sus funcionalidades llamado: `now()` el cual será una instancia de [`Illuminate\Support\Carbon`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-now)
- *Asumo* de lo que expone tu consulta que solo buscas filtrar basándote en *año-mes-día*; de ser esto así entonces también como dejaba en los comentarios debes usar la función: [**`whereDate`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

  - Lo anterior te ayudará a que dicho método solo tome la marca de fecha del valor que contiene la columna indicada (*en este caso el `created_at`*)
- Tampoco necesitas formatear la salida de `now()` con el uso de `format`

  - Al menos en este caso tampoco ayuda pues lo que estás formateando solo es la marca de fecha/tiempo que te da `now` pero el problema sigue en el valor que devuelve `created_at` que por estar empleando `where` no es capaz de formatear a la estructura esperada para que funcione en este caso.
  - Y como en el primer punto, de hecho es redundante **pues el método que propongo que uses `wherDate`** perteneciente al *Builder de Database* formatea el tercer parámetro a *año-mes-dia* si es que este *es una instancia de `DateTimeInterface`* (**por eso en este caso es mejor preferir su uso al simple `where`**)

**Consulta errónea**

Imagina que la consulta se vería así:

```
$rate = Rate::where('2020-11-03 12:00:00', '2020-11-03')->first();
```

Lo anterior por supuesto **no** te va a generar salida alguna.

**Entonces tu consulta sería así para que funcione**:

```
$rate = Rate::whereDate('created_at', now())->first(); // o get si necesitas como salida una colección
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!